# webglcontextcreationerror event: is it triggered synchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

Is the [webglcontextcreationerror event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/webglcontextcreationerror) triggered synchronously or asynchronously? For example does

```
canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextcreationerror", function() {
  console.log("Error");
});
var context = canvas.getContext("webgl");
console.log("After creation");
```

in the case of error output

```
"After creation"
"Error"
```

or

```
"Error"
"After creation"
```

?

I am unsure how to force this event to find out the answer myself.

Comment: Isn't an event always and by definition asynchronous ? Interestingly enough , when you first request a 2D context and then a webgl one, the event doesn't fire (at least on FF) even though "*the user agent is unable to create a WebGLRenderingContext context*" So I just tried on chrome and it does fire the event, synchronously... But webkit had bugs with events firing before the flow of synchronous calls are finished so I don't know if it can be a real and solid answer.

Comment: "Isn't an event always and by definition asynchronous" I don't think so... The triggering (/dispatching) of it can be done at the programmer's discretion. For example https://plnkr.co/edit/kYrcNjWHFaZ1WYYrgsOY?p=preview triggers a custom event synchronously.

Comment: Ok so you're right and the the answer is yes it's synchronous, you can test it with `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextcreationerror", function() {
  console.log("Error");
});
canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.getContext("webgl");
console.log("After creation");` in chrome.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah great! Trying to create a 2d context after the webgl context is a way to force the error. Feel free to add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NB** : This is not a per spec answer, but only from a single UA test, so it may be wrong, or at least true only to this UA, a.k.a Chrome.

---

In chrome, to force the error event, you can first request a 2dContext then a webgl one.

This way we can see that this UA does treat the event as an synchronous one.
 <sub>I just learn about these right-now...</sub>

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextcreationerror", function() {
  snippet.log("Error");
});

canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.getContext("webgl");

snippet.log("After creation");
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

So one question is why do you care the order? `getContext` returns `null` on failure so if you want to know if it failed then you're done. `webglcontextcreationerror`'s only point is for you to get the reason why it failed since `getContext` has no way to do that. So, you could structure your code such that it doesn't matter whether it's sync or async

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

function doSomethingWithStatusMessage(e) {
  log("context creation error: "+ e.statusMessage);
}

canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextcreationerror", doSomethingWithStatusMessage);

log("2d: " + canvas.getContext('2d'));
log("webgl: " + canvas.getContext("webgl"));
log("after creation");

function log(msg, color) {
  var div = document.createElement("pre");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

`doSomethingWithStatus` message could do anything you want. Assume based on `getContext` you display a dialog.

```
if (!canvas.getContext("webgl")) {
   g_dialog = new Dialog("can't create context", g_reason);
}
```

Then you might have code like

```
var g_reason = "unknown";
var g_dialog;

function doSomethingWithStatusMessage(e) {
  if (g_dialog) {
    g_dialog.updateReason(e.statusMessage);
  } else {
    g_reason = g.statusMessage;
  }
}

function Dialog(msg, reason) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  var reasonNode = document.createTextNode("");
  div.appendChild(reasonNode);
  updateReason(reason);      

  function updateReason(reason) {
    reasonNode.nodeValue = reason;
  }
  this.updateReason = updateReason;
}
```

```js
var g_reason = "unknown";
var g_dialog;

function doSomethingWithStatusMessage(e) {
  if (g_dialog) {
    g_dialog.updateReason(e.statusMessage);
  } else {
    g_reason = e.statusMessage;
  }
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextcreationerror", doSomethingWithStatusMessage);

log("2d: " + canvas.getContext('2d'));
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
log("webgl: " + gl);
log("after creation");

if (!gl) {
  new Dialog("could not create WebGL context: ", g_reason);
}

function log(msg, color) {
  var div = document.createElement("pre");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function Dialog(msg, reason) {
  var outer = document.createElement("div");
  outer.className = "dialog";
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  var reasonNode = document.createTextNode("");
  div.appendChild(reasonNode);
  outer.appendChild(div);
  updateReason(reason);      
  document.body.appendChild(outer);
  outer.addEventListener('click', close);

  function updateReason(reason) {
    reasonNode.nodeValue = reason;
  }
  
  function close() {
    document.body.removeChild(outer);
    outer.removeEventListener('click', close);
  }
  
  this.close = close;
  this.updateReason = updateReason;
}
```

```css
.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If instead you wanted to report the error to a server for example then just trigger it a few moments later to give the async message a chance to arrive.

```
if (!canvas.getContext("webgl")) {
   // give a moment for the async message to arrive
   setTimeout(uploadReason, 1000);
}
```

The rest would just be

```
var g_reason = "unknown";

function doSomethingWithStatusMessage(e) {
  g_reason = e.statusMessage;
}

function uploadReason() {
  .. XHR g_reason to server ..
}
```

Note: I [file a bug on this part of the spec](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/1603) so you can follow up if you'd like.

Comment: Ah good point about returning null so depending on that. I will probably do that in my code.