# Can browsers throw errors when trying to create a rendering context?

Tags: javascript, canvas, browser, cross-browser

Could the following code ever throw an error?

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("somethingwrong");
```

In chromium, it does just return null.

How would it be if the the requested rendering context is known to a browser? (Like "webgl" or "experimental-webgl") Is there the possibility of an error exception? In chromium I could not provoke this behavior.

In other words: Do I need to wrap this code in a try/catch in a library that checks cleanly for a rendering context?

Is there maybe a way to objectify this? E.g. by a web service that tries a code snipped in different browsers and lists their possibly differing results.

Comment: Yes, for me it looks like this as well. But there might be a browser supporting "2d" contexts and no others. But even when I disable webgl, I get null as a return value. With the creation, I'm not sure if there could be an exception, since document.createElement("something") for me returns undefined without exception.

Comment: not a dupe but related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565598/webglcontextcreationerror-event-is-it-triggered-synchronously/36566263#36566263 Also, the fact that this event does exist means that yes, browsers **can** throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I knew about the "webglcontextcreationerror" event. I'm not 100% percent sure about the terminology here, but I'd argue that this is not throwing an error, since I cannot catch it (with try/catch) at another place. I'd say, this is a regular event, which is is ocasionally called "...error". But please, someone correct me, if I'm wrong here,

Answer (score 1):

Returning `null` is the [expected behavior](https://developers.whatwg.org/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-getcontext) if the requested context is not available, or if the canvas has already been assigned to a different type of context:

> Returns `null` if the given context ID is not supported, if the canvas
>   has already been initialized with the other context type (e.g. trying
>   to get a "2d" context after getting a "webgl" context).

There are special cases where an exception can be thrown related to proxy scenarios (ibid):

> Throws an `InvalidStateError` exception if the `setContext()` or
>   `transferControlToProxy()` methods have been used.

In addition to that, even though a browser may support a certain type of context there is no guarantee that the object can be created if the system resources such as memory are low in which case `null` would be returned.

**[Here is an overview](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-canvas-getcontext)** of what will be returned in different (common) scenarios.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sza86.png]

So unless you are using proxy transfers (which is not exactly widely supported at this time) you do not need to use `try-catch` with `getContext()`.

Tip: in the future canvas will get a property `probablySupportsContext()` which can be used before `getContext()`. This will do these tests and return `false` if conditions are not met (supported context, already in use with different context type, low resources etc.):

```
var supported = canvas . probablySupportsContext(contextId [, ... ] )
```

> Returns false if calling `getContext()` with the same arguments would
>   definitely return null, and true otherwise.

**Update** Just wanted to elaborate on a special case - for *vendor specific* extensions it is in theory possible to get an exception thrown depending on that very specific extension and how it defines its behavior. But these are and should not be considered part of the standard and since they are experimental in most cases, a risk and non-standard behavior is implied.

Comment: This was a very helpful post. It confirms my guess, that a try/catch is not necessary here (provided that no proxy computation is used). The only doubt remains about the "vendor-specific extensions", like "experimental-webgl". But probably errors inside those would be captured by the "webglcontextcreationerror" event.

Comment: Just for completeness: In the official repo of the Khronos group, the wrapper for creating a webgl context is indeed using a try/catch. That made me wondering. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/demos/common/webgl-utils.js

Comment: I saw a comment on the whatwg mailing list to the effect that an older version of Firefox *erroneously* threw from `getContext` when it failed, in certain cases, which probably explains the try/catch.  As far as I can tell, this is no longer possible.

Also, you should be safe to save the error reason raised (in your handler) and use it immediately (outside the handler), because the event is [almost definitely raised synchronously](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/1603).

Comment: I've noticed that Tor Browser (a Firefox fork) will throw when attempting to create certain blocked webgl contexts.